# PetaPoco sample application for Windows forms

Tags: c#, sql, petapoco

I came accross  [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) and decided to give it a try
Did anyone come accross a sample WindowsForms app with this? So far I only found sample web application.

I understand the concept of PetaPoco that is similar to NHibranate but I failed to find an example to see how to bind a Grid to the result of the query. Best would be a sample app if anyone got one on hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a Winform DataGridView like this:

```
    Dim ppdb = New PetaPoco.Database("Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security=True;", "System.Data.SqlClient")
    Dim blTable = New BindingList(Of TableItem)(ppdb.Query(Of TableItem)("select * from table").ToList)
    Dim bsTable As New BindingSource(blTable, "")
    DataGridView.DataSource = bsTable
```

You'll need to save the objects back to the database if you want to keep your changes.

To get the POCO bound to a row, use:

```
Dim obj = DataGridView.Rows(RowIndex).DataBoundItem
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just bind directly to the `List<T>` returned from `public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string sql, params object[] args)` - example taken from line 752 in PetaPoco.cs @ [source on GitHub](https://github.com/toptensoftware/PetaPoco/blob/master/PetaPoco/PetaPoco.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Even it's quite old thread, maybe someone will need this.
Bind directly to List and that's it.

```
    using (var db = new PetaPoco.Database(string_connection, string_provider))
    {
        try
        {
            var ret = db.Query<MyTable>("select * from my_table_name").ToList();

            if(ret != null)
            {
                dgv.DataSource = ret; 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message); 
        }
    } // using
```